# How to add reference of dynamically created assembly, which was created using rosyln. After assembly generated rerun the application throws exception

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

How to add reference of dynamically created assembly, which was created using rosyln compilrt.  After assembly file created to the file system.

```
string path = Path.Combine(tempDir, assemblyFileName);
var pdbFilePath = Path.Combine(tempDir, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assemblyFileName) + ".pdb");            
emitResult = compilation.Emit(path, pdbFilePath);
```

Re running the application throws exceptions.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'RunTimeRules.XRefRule' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) 

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine.RunTimeRules.XRefRule' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine.RunTimeRules.XRefRule
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine.RunTimeRules.XRefRule | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projects/RE/Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Projects\RE\Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Projects\RE\Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: H:\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/I705472/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/e110b058/8e2e9773/Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine.RunTimeRules.XRefRule.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/I705472/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/e110b058/8e2e9773/Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine.RunTimeRules.XRefRule/Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine.RunTimeRules.XRefRule.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/RE/Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine/bin/Jpmc.Cib.Msr.RuleEngine.RunTimeRules.XRefRule.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: NAME
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

This assembly was dynamically generated assembly. Do I need to include as part of any one existing Project Reference?. As its not referenced anywhere but its part of bin folder so it throws the exception